# Take every nth row and transpose them while keeping the link

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following big table like it is shown on the left side in the picture (columns A and B only).

I want to get the table to the right of it that says GOAL.

I want to take every 3rd row of column B (values 11, 654, and 4546), and put them into a table to the right under GOAL. The idea is that I want to keep the link between E4 and B4 so that if I change B4 or B11 or B18, then they will be changed in E4, F4, and G4 respectively.

I tried using the OFFSET function, but it only works if I drag it down the column and not across the columns.

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

**EDIT:** My data looks more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do without the volatile Offset. If your rule is that the desired value is three cells down from the year number, then find the row of the year number with Match, add 3 to that row number and use Index() take the value from column B for that calculated number:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(E3,$A:$A,0)+3)
```

Note that the references to the columns A and B are fixed with the $ sign, so they don't change when the formula is copied across, but the reference to E3 is relative, so it will adjust to F3, G3, etc. when copied across.

[image]

Comment: I figured it out by using your example. The final answer is =INDEX($F:$F;MATCH(I3;$B:$B;3)+4)

Comment: Can you please look also at the new data? The 1990 Total line screws up the results.

Comment: You use a `3` as the last argument of Match(). Where did that come from? The last argument of Match() must be 0 -- as I posted in my formula -- to find an exact match. Then it will find the FIRST occurrence of the number. If you use any number bigger than 0 for the last argument of Match(), then it will do an approximate match and your data is not suited for that. Then it will return unpredictable / wrong results.